# Different bindings within same function app

Tags: azure-functions

Is it possible to have different batchsize bindings within same azure function app? I need some functions to run 3 instances and others 1. Having them in multiple function apps would require complex deployment.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. can you please post some code example of what you have so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you create a queueTrigger and then you want to set mutiple batchsize?

Can not do that. On local batchsize is setted in json file. It is setted for whole function app. not just for a binding.

Comment: So it can only be set for the complete function in the host file and not pr function within the function app?

Comment: @ThomasSegato Yes, there is no way. Batchsize is a value of `host.json` about queuetrigger that acts on the entire Function App. There is no documentation show that it can be set in a single function.

Comment: Thanks - appreciated.